# Wrong Android Studio All Attributes Panel

Tags: android, attributes, panel

Android Studio was working ok, but my all attributes panel is wrong, I see a few attributes in XML (in the attributes panel) and many of them are missing.

How can I reset the original view of my all attributes panel?
[My wrong all attributes panel in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVsWE.png)

Comment: Question is unclear. What is the original view intended.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Click on setting tab in attribute list and select XML attribute editor. Please check below images: -[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gXMD.png)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5U96.png)